# Tengo dos botones que abren un pop up, funcionan bien pero en safari en macbook no funcionan(en chrome si) y en iphone ni en safari ni chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que mas extraño me parece es que en macbook si funcione en chrome pero en iphone no.

aca se crea el boton con js y se le agrega al evento onclick la funcion que abre el pop up

```
    <button id="confirmarcotizacion-' + data.d[i].ProductoID + '-' + data.d[i].ModalidadEntregaID + '" style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit"\
                                    data-conceptofacturacion="' + data.d[i].ConceptoFacturacion + '" \
                                    data-unidadventa="' + data.d[i].UnidadVenta + '" \
                                    data-agenciaretiro="' + data.d[i].AgenciaRetiro + '" \
                                    data-modalidadentregaid="' + data.d[i].ModalidadEntregaID + '" \
                                    data-agenciaiddestino="' + data.d[i].AgenciaIDDestino + '" \
                                    data-importetotal="' + valoresCotizacion.ImporteTotal.toFixed(2) + '" \
                                    data-volumentotal="' + VolumenTotal + '" \
                                    data-valorconversionm3="' + data.d[i].ValorConversionM3 + '" \
                                    class="btnblue3" onclick="abreModalAgencias();return false;">Confirmar</button>\
```

el evento onclick que se le asigna en el mismo html llama a esta funcion(lei en otras preguntas que esto puede ser el problema pero hay otros botones creados de la misma forma y con el onclick en el codigo html que funcionan bien en apple)

aca está el css del boton por si ayuda de algo

```
.listaCotizacionesItem button {
background-color: #004993 !important;
color: #fff !important;
font-family: 'Fira Sans' !important;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 36%);
!important: ;
border-radius: 3px !important;
border: 0 !important;
font-weight: 600 !important;
font-style: italic !important;
```

}

Comment: Recuerda que hay navegadores que necesitan que se le incluyan prefijos especiales para asegurar la compatibilidad de características de CSS, puedes usar `https://autoprefixer.github.io/` para validar que tu código cuente con los prefijos adecuados para otros navegadores.

Comment: @JhonMaldonado muchas gracias! lo revisare usando esa herramienta que me pasaste.